# Why do my files in vscode keep being deleted after trying to execute them?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am currently learning to code with python in vscode but recently I have been having problems with file seemingly deleting themselves after attempted execution (image 1). I have tried Ctrl+z and I have tried recovering them but neither have worked. The files are not in my recycling bin either. If I try to create a new file of the same name in the same folder it shows me a error message (image 2) of "unable to resolve non-existing files"

When I execute my code the file saves but then becomes deleted:

[image: When I execute my code the file saves but then becomes deleted]

This message appears if I try to undo the delete:

[image: This message appears if I try to undo the delete]

Comment: Is there someone with access to your computer, and willing to pull a destructive prank on you?  This looks like your IDE has been configured to use `rm` as the command to execute your program, rather than `python`.

Comment: No this is a private computer so there shouldn't be any problems with someone messing anything up

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to restart vscode? It is recommended that you could try the following aspects:

1. Check if there is any effect caused by the related expansion. For example, LaTeX Workshop extension has the function of cleaning generated files.
2. Check your [setting.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) Files,clear the contents of the user setting.json file and the vs code will return to the default value.

If it still doesn't work, you could consider installing vscode again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I re-installed vscode a few days ago, and since then haven't had any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Python file through a command prompt or terminal using the command `python <foo_file_name>`. Doing this will either confirm or deny the theory that @jasonharper made in the comments.
If you can run the script that way then we know that @jasonharper was correct and somehow your execute button/command was tampered with.

Comment: The same [Errno 2] message comes up in the command prompt.

Comment: @Ccav can you try creating the file in command prompt/terminal using a text editor and run it the same way. If that doesn't work it seems like something with your execute command is not working or that it's been remapped somehow

Comment: I have already tried that, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the Same problem with a PHP file, and turns out it wasn´t VS CODE. It was my antivirus that was moving the file to quarentine!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this may indeed be the case, it would be helpful if you could point out what OS and antivirus system you're using ;)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: I applied similar solution to a similar problem. In my case there was a Dockerfile trying to install some windows packages. I had WindowsDefender running on my Linux machine (this was applied to my computer by IT. Windows Defender thought, the lines of code are harmful so it decided to delete the file from disk.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using a different programming language. Building generated a file that got deleted automatically.
In my case the Windows 10 default antivirus was the cause. Turned off real-time scanning, tried again and then my files weren't deleted.
Adding an exception for the folder fixed it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31543371)